# Visual Studio Report - Show a table in two rows

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, report, ssrs-tablix

i have a question: is there any way to show a single row of a table in two rows? The problem is that my table has too many fields and is too wide. So, I think that maybe you can split each row in the table to make it in a row. For example (my idea in Excel, just for example):

Complete table
[image]

...and my idea
[image]

I hope for your help!

Comment: I'm not sure how or if you can do this but... just want to say I think it's a bad idea and will cause confusion. When I see a new row I think that it's a new row, not a continuation of the old one. Personally I would look at scaling or scrolling first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can:

1. add a `Tablix` with 4 columns and without header
2. add a `Rectangle` in every detail cell
3. add 4 `TextBox` for every `Rectangle`: use 2 `TextBox` as labels and two `TextBox` as values
4. increase `Rectangle` height in order to put spaces between every rows

[image]

Once you perform this operation for value 1 and 5, you can copy and paste `Rectangle` in the other 3 cells and simply change label and value.

Comment: Rectangles that have label with [Value] inside, can adapt its height depending of content? Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I don't think there is problem regarding `Rectangle` behaviour but your comment highlights a problem that I didn't consider: if a `TextBox` grow more than the others on the same line the table structure will be lost. So it is better set every `TextBox` `CanGrow` property to `False` and choose a fixed height in order to display a maximum of 2-3 rows in a single `TextBox`.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the TextBox. I'll try to do this